# YT-1300 light freighter in Star Wars motion pictures?

Tags: star-wars

The Millennium Falcon is a model YT-1300 light freighter built by 
Corellian Engineering Corporation. Are there any appearances of this same model of ship in the Star Wars motion pictures other than the Millennium Falcon?

(By Star Wars Motion Pictures, I specifically mean Episodes I-VII and Rogue One)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. As easter eggs, YT-1300 appeared in:

- Episode II (Attack of the Clones) has TWO side by side YT-1300s (lower left corner) when Padme and Anakin arrive on Naboo.

  [image: Two YT-1300s on Naboo]
- Episode III (Revenge of the Sith) has pre-Lando-ownership (and thus unmodified) Millenium Falcon ([as per Lucas](http://web.archive.org/web/20050829225514/http://www.starwars.com/episode-iii/bts/production/f20050526/index.html))

  [image: YT-1300 Landing]

---

Sources:

- http://furiousfanboys.com/2010/06/the-best-star-wars-easter-eggs/
- http://www.eeggs.com/items/44724.html